# SQL counting from multiple sources

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables `Student` and `Enrolment` with the following fields:

Student: StudentID, Name, Level

Enrolment: Ref, StudentID, Course, EnrolDate

I'm trying to get the total number of students who are enrolled since 13/10/2013 with the `Name` 'john smith'.

I have been able to COUNT the number of students enrolled since a specific date but I can't do the name part of it.

Code so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(ref)
AS NumOfStudents
FROM Enrolment
WHERE EnrolDate> '2013/10/13'
```

Thank You.

Comment: This is what I have so far, after this statement I only need students with specific name.

SELECT COUNT(ref)
AS NumOfStudents
FROM Enrolment
WHERE EnrolDate> '2013/10/13'

Comment: Ok, then use a join (See my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM Student S INNER JOIN
     Enrolment E ON S.StudentID=E.StudentID
WHERE E.EnrolDate>'2013-10-13'
AND S.Name='john smith'
```

**OR** using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM Student S INNER JOIN
     Enrolment E ON S.StudentID=E.StudentID
WHERE E.EnrolDate>'2013-10-13'
AND S.Name LIKE '%john smith%'
```

The second query will return if the name contains 'john smith'. For example, Name like 'john smith A'

Answer (score 1):

Try this query,

```
select count(*) ans_field
from Student s, Enrolment e
where s.StudentID=e.StudentID and e.Enrolment > '2013-10-13' and s.Name like '%John smith%'
```